# Setting up a cluster in Hadoop - JPS does not show NodeManager and ResourceManager

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, distributed-computing, resourcemanager, nodemanager

I am trying configure Hadoop in pseudo-distributed mode. `start-dfs.sh` works perfectly. `jps` gives the following output (starts all the daemons properly):

```
26051 NameNode
26533 SecondaryNameNode
29381 Jps
26237 DataNode
```

However, `start-yarn.sh` fails to start nodemanager and resourcemanager. `jps` gives same output as the one after using `start-dfs.sh`:

```
26051 NameNode
26533 SecondaryNameNode
29381 Jps
26237 DataNode
```

The log file for resourcemanager gives the following:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2 (file:/home/nikhil/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-4.0.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31422
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 31422
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
Oct 14, 2019 8:07:14 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver as a provider class
Oct 14, 2019 8:07:14 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.RMWebServices as a root resource class
Oct 14, 2019 8:07:14 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler as a provider class
Oct 14, 2019 8:07:14 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'
Oct 14, 2019 8:07:14 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
```

The log file for nodemanager is as below:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31422
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 31422
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2 (file:/home/nikhil/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-4.0.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Oct 14, 2019 8:09:07 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.webapp.NMWebServices as a root resource class
Oct 14, 2019 8:09:07 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler as a provider class
Oct 14, 2019 8:09:07 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver as a provider class
Oct 14, 2019 8:09:07 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'
Oct 14, 2019 8:09:07 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
```

`java --version` gives the following:

```
java 13 2019-09-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13+33)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13+33, mixed mode, sharing)
```

`hadoop version` outputs:

```
Hadoop 3.2.1
Source code repository https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r b3cbbb467e22ea829b3808f4b7b01d07e0bf3842
Compiled by rohithsharmaks on 2019-09-10T15:56Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 776eaf9eee9c0ffc370bcbc1888737
This command was run using /home/nikhil/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.2.1.jar
```

Kindly help me start nodemanager and resourcemanager. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed by installing Oracle Java 8 instead of Java 11. None of the versions of hadoop till now support Java versions > 8.